# PHP: append string value to array

Tags: php, arrays, append

I'm relatively new to PHP and I don't understand why my code is failing to append string values to an array.

From everything I've read on the topic, this code:

```
global $tom_period_parent_title;

$tom_period_parent_title = array();

$tom_period_parent_title[] = 'test';
array_push ($tom_period_parent_title, 'tester');
```

Should I believe produce this result:

```
tom_period_parent_title
Array
(
    [0] => 'test'
    [1] => 'tester'
)
```

But for some reason I don't understand and have failed to find any mention of on the web, I'm getting this:

```
tom_period_parent_title
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
)
```

Can anybody please help me understand how to make this work?

Comment: Show us your **real** code.

Comment: How are you getting `0` and `1`? https://eval.in/418483

Comment: I should have specified, this is a global variable. I'm reading global variables with Debug This, which I think is trustworthy.

Comment: What is `Debug This`? Run `print_r($tom_period_parent_title);` after your array_push.

Comment: I just copied and ran your code and it produces exactly what you want... add `print_r(  $tom_period_parent_title )` at the end of your code to see..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to chris85 for showing me how to discover using printr() that my code does in fact work. The problem is the debugger I've been using, Debug This for Wordpress, which it turns out is incorrectly reporting my global array variable contents. I reported the problem on its support page. I hope I don't get too much negative rep for this misunderstanding. Thanks to all.